# Trying to Add record to a table getting an error "Cannot add records(s); join key of table 'item' not in recordset"

Tags: ms-access

Hello I am trying to create a form which will let me insert an item Name, Price and Description.

I got an error about adding the supplier, so I added the supplier name to the item form and now I get the error `Cannot add records(s); join key of table 'item' not in record set` and it wont let me type in the fields. I have looked online to try and resolve my issue but it did not help. If you have any help it would be greatly appreciated.

I have attached photos of my tables and forms.

### Item Form

[image: 1]

### Supplier Table

[image: 2]

### Item Table

[image: 3]

### Relationships

[image: 4]

Comment: Is form bound to table and textboxes bound to fields? What code is behind the button?

Comment: You need to show us the record source of the form.

Comment: @Andre Which part of the record source do you want to see or do you want to see all of it?

Comment: @June7 the Name and textboxes are bounded together and i haven't added any extra code, its the default code for a button to add a record.

Comment: Edit question to show the form RecordSource. Does it just reference table or is it a query? If it is a query, show the SQL statement. Not sure what 'default' code would be. I don't let wizards build code for me. Is it an embedded macro? If form is bound, why would you even need code to save data?

Comment: @June7 https://imgur.com/a/N0LaZsE I added some photos of the recordsouce and it reference a different table. I also added a photo for the button code.

Comment: Should edit question to include the new info as text, not images. I don't see a query in the images anyway. Don't use query. Bind form to table and see what happens.